# Not able to create second queue by code

Tags: c#, asp.net, msmq

I'm creating two queues in code if they don't already exist at `Page_Load`. The code runs fine for the first queue, but failed to set its `Authenticate` property on the second queue. I'm running Visual Studio as Administrator and can create those queues with the MSMQ UI. Both queues were created when I look in the UI, but the second one didn't have the property set.

```
if (MessageQueue.Exists(path1) == false)
{
    var q = MessageQueue.Create(path1, true);
    q.Authenticate = true;
}

if (MessageQueue.Exists(path2) == false)
{
    var q = MessageQueue.Create(path2, true); // <-- didn't fail here
    q.Authenticate = true; // <-- failed here
}
```

Error message:

> The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.

Comment: Where does the path get defined? Maybe there is a permissions issue with the path you have defined in `path2`.

Comment: @ShaneVanWyk, both paths are in Public Queues so they share permissions. I tried a few more times, the results seem random. Sometimes even fail on the first one.

Comment: Not very familiar with `MSMQ`, One thing that you could try is delegating the 2 Queues. Like running it in different threads.